# Regex: Replace lowercase letters to Capital letters in < tags > at the beginning of words

Tags: regex, windows, notepad++

I have this regex:

Search: `(\w+)([A-Z])`
Replace by: `\u$1$2`

This will replace all the first letter of words into capital letter. For example:

`My mother is home -> My Mother Is Home`

Now, in the same way I want to replace all the words from the `<title></title>` tag, from multiple files.

I write this regex, but does not convert lowercase letters at the beginning of words in uppercase (from the tag)

> Search: `<title>(\w+)([A-Z])</title>`
>
> Replace by: `\u$1$2`

Can anyone help me a little bit? For example:

`<title>My mother is home</title>` should become `<title>My Mother Is Home</title>`

Comment: *doesn't work* is an absolutely useless problem description unless you explain specifically what **doesn't work** means. Do you get an error? If so,  what is the exact error message? Does it replace the text incorrectly, or does it not replace at all? We can't see your screen or read your mind, so it's your responsibility to explain the **specific problem** you're having, and *doesn't work* does not do so.

Comment: does not convert lowercase letters at the beginning of words in uppercase (from the tag)

Comment: I already answered a very similar question on another SO site. Let me see...

Comment: Whatdo you need to do with ALLCAPS words? Try `(?:\G(?!^)|<title>)\s*\K([^<\s])([^<\s]*)` and replace with `\u$1\L$2`

Comment: hello Wiktor. I have a lot of titles in html files, whose first letter is not capitalized. So I have to search and replace all from `<title>`

Comment: WORKS  !!!! Thanks. But please explain in an answer what exactly does `\G` and `\K` in this case

Comment: I would suggest *not* using a regular-expression-based solution to manipulate HTML or XML, but rather something that understands those languages. That way you can extract and replace "the text content of the `<title>` element" instead of trying to finagle a way to match that concept with regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following regex solution:

*Find What*:     `(?:\G(?!^)|<title>)\s*\K([^<\s])([^<\s]*)` 
*Replace With*: `\u$1\L$2`

**Details**:

- `(?:\G(?!^)|<title>)` - either `<title>` or the end of the previous successful match
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\K`  - a match reset operator
- `([^<\s])` - Capture group 1: any char but a `<` or whitespace
- `([^<\s]*)` - any 0+ chars other than whitespace and `<`.

The `\u$1` turns the Group 1 starting char (and it is the only one) to upper case and `\L$2` turns all the rest of the match to lower case.

[image]

Comment: what does `\G` ?

Comment: `\G` is an anchor that matches a position at the start of the string or after the preceding successful match. It ensures consecutive matches are only found. I temper `\G` with a negative lookahead to "subtract" the start of string position match.

Comment: by the way, Wictor. One more scenario. If I have something like this: `<span class="call"><a href="the-realm-in-which-fantasy-rules.html" class="linkMare">The realm in which fantasy rules</a></span>` How can I update your regex considering the fact that there are many different <a href links and other tags in this case

Comment: oh, I got it:  `(?:\G(?!^)|class="linkMare">)\s*\K([^<\s])([^<\s]*)`

Comment: The part after `\G(?!^)|` defines a match after which consecutive matches are searched for.